# TypeError: argument of type 'MX' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, dns, iterable

```
import dns.resolver
answer=dns.resolver.resolve("google.com", "MX")
for data in answer:
    print (data)
    if "smtp.google.com" in data:
      print("cool")
```

Despite my efforts, I keep receiving this error.

TypeError: argument of type 'MX' is not iterable

Comment: You may want to first try to look at what type is `answer` exactly... It is not a string nor  a list of strings.

Comment: See first example on page https://www.dnspython.org/examples/, which is exactly your need and shows how to iterate in the reply. Pro tip in general, unrelated to DNS: don't name a variable `data` as it does not say anything about what it holds.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick mentioned in the question comments, the variable “data” is not a list of strings, rather it’s a [dns.retypes.MX.MX](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rdata-subclasses.html#dns.rdtypes.ANY.MX.MX). If you want to see if the mail exchange host matches “smtp.google.com”, you could do something like this:

```
import dns.resolver
answers = dns.resolver.resolve("google.com", "MX")
for rdata in answers:
    print(rdata.exchange)
    print(rdata.priority)
    if "smtp.google.com" == rdata.exchange:
        print("cool")
```